# Maintaining scope with class pointers in c++

Tags: c++

I have a class that is responsible for creating and initializing a number of large objects, as the objects are all of the same Type and I don't want to repeat the same initializing code for all the objects, I call an Init method for each object, for example:

```
InitObject(objMember);

void Test::InitObject(LargeObject * obj)
{
    obj = new LargeObject;
    obj->Load();
    obj->SetSomeProperty(false);
}
```

Once this has been done, from a public method I call a set of methods to get a pointer to each of the objects:

```
//public
LargeObject * Test::GetObject()
{
    return objMember;
}
```

The issue is that the objects are losing scope, when InitObject is called, the objects are correctly constructed and populated, but when I call GetObject, it has lost everything.

I'm probably missing something trivial, but I can't see why it's going out of scope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is trivial, yes. You're initializing a copy of the original pointer. You probably want to pass it by reference:

```
void Test::InitObject(LargeObject*& obj)
```

Passing by value means that you're assigning the return of `new` to a copy of the pointer. The one outside the function `InitObject` remains unchanged.

A few more things - initializing objects after construction should be done with care. If the object isn't valid after construction, it's a bad design (excluding some rare cases). You can signal invalid initialization by throwing an exception from the constructor.

Also, consider using smart pointers instead of raw pointers.

Comment: Wow, thanks! I'm still new to c++, I had thought by using * I was passing it by reference.

Comment: Thanks, I am throwing exceptions in the constructor and will take a look at smart pointers.